# jQuery detect image size

Tags: jquery, image, image-size

With the following function I can apply the img width to its surrounding div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.imagecontainer').each(function() {
    $(this).width( $(this).find('img').attr('width') );
  });

});
```

The problem is that this only works, when the img has a width attribute. How can I add the img width to the surrounding .imagecontainer div, even when the img tag doesnt have a width attribute? I can display the image width with the load() function, but have no glue how to apply it to the divs width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `attr` gives the attribute value and if not defined it would not work. You can use

```
   $(this).width = $(this).find('img').width;
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(this).find('img').width()
```

this will work